# cURL in PHP only partially removing headers

Tags: php, curl, wamp

**Running Out Of Sanity**

I have looked high and low and lost a bit of my life and a lot of my sanity trying to return a cURL POST request. Everything works fine except I cannot remove the headers. Oh yes I have tried

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
```

What worse is that when I try

```
$headerLength = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
```

I get a return of 25 which is completely wrong. Please help I am at my wits end with this one.

So I call this method

```
      $service = new RestfulService($Url1);
      $response = $service->request('', 'POST', $tokenXml, null,
array(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING =>'UTF-8'));
```

Which in turn calls (using SilverStripe framework)

```
public function curlRequest($url, $method, $data = null, $headers = null, $curlOptions = array()) {
    $ch        = curl_init();
    $timeout   = 5;
    $sapphireInfo = new SapphireInfo(); 
    $useragent = 'SilverStripe/' . $sapphireInfo->Version();
    $curlOptions = $curlOptions + (array)$this->config()->default_curl_options;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    if(!ini_get('open_basedir')) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    //include headers in the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    // Add headers
    if($this->customHeaders) {
        $headers = array_merge((array)$this->customHeaders, (array)$headers);
    }

    if($headers) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    // Add authentication
    if($this->authUsername) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->getBasicAuthString());

    // Add fields to POST and PUT requests
    if($method == 'POST') {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    } elseif($method == 'PUT') {
        $put = fopen("php://temp", 'r+');               
        fwrite($put, $data);
        fseek($put, 0); 

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $put);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($data)); 
    }

    // Apply proxy settings
    if(is_array($this->proxy)) {
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $this->proxy);
    }

    // Set any custom options passed to the request() function
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);

    // Run request
    $rawResponse = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch))    var_dump(curl_error($ch));


    $response = $this->extractResponse($ch, $rawResponse);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

When I dump the response, the remove header command only removes the first few characters. Like so...

```
object(RestfulService_Response)[1065]
  protected 'simpleXML' => null
  protected 'cachedResponse' => boolean false
  protected 'statusCode' => int 100
  protected 'statusDescription' => string 'Continue' (length=8)
  protected 'headers' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'body' => string 'ontrol: no-cache

Pragma: no-cache

Content-Length: 3593

Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8

Expires: Fri, 20 Sep 2013 01:14:14 GMT

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"

X-XSS-Protection: 0

PPServer: PPV: 30 H: CO1IDOLGN62 V: 0

Date: Fri, 20 Sep 2013 01:15:13 GMT

Connection: close



�<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envel
```

Has it got anything to do with the strange character before the

Update: I have checked this code on my colleagues computer, he doesn't have any problems. I am running WAMP my colleague is on a MAC, could there be any set up issues? I have downloaded the most recent curl.dll and added it to my php library, still no cigar.

Any ideas???

Comment: My first thought is: encoding. There might also be a problem with line endings.

Comment: Thanks George you put me on the right track I needed to add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3) as it was not understanding the encoding

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my case the encoding was incorrect I needed to add the following option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3)
```

Works fine now